# Optimizing SELECT using array intersection

Tags: postgresql

Inside a Before trigger function, I'm trying to optimize a SELECT which uses an array intersection of the form:

`select into matching_product * from products where global_ids && NEW.global_ids`

The above is pegging the cpu at 100% while doing some modest batch inserts. (without the above select in the trigger function the cpu drops to ~5%)

I did define a GIN-index on `global_ids` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any other way to optimize the above? E.g.: Should I just go ahead and create a N-M relationship between products and global_ids and do some joins to get the same result?

**EDIT**

Seems the GIN-index IS used, however it's still slow. Not sure what I can expect, (YMMV and all that) but the table has ~200,000 items. Doing a query like below takes 300ms. I feel this should be near instant.

`select * from products where global_ids && '{871712323629}'`

Doing an explain on the above shows:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on products  (cost=40.51..3443.85 rows=1099 width=490)
Recheck Cond: (global_ids && '{871712323629}'::text[])
->  Bitmap Index Scan on "global_ids_GIN"  (cost=0.00..40.24 rows=1099 width=0)
Index Cond: (global_ids && '{871712323629}'::text[])
```

Table definition, removed irrelevant columns

```
CREATE TABLE public.products
(
    id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    global_ids text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Index

```
CREATE INDEX "global_ids_GIN"
    ON public.products USING gin
    (global_ids COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Have you tried to cast `NEW.global_ids` explicity to jsonb? (`(NEW.global_ids)::jsonb`). Perhaps the planner doesn't use the GIN index because the trigger function can't predict what data type will `NEW.global_ids` be.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister I thought the question was about arrays...

Comment: Use [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) with `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0` and `auto_explain.log_nested_statement = on` and check if the statements really oesn't use the index. Please add the table and inex definition to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: please so edit. Thanks

Comment: Can you also capture the execution plan of the query inside the function using `auto_explain`? Another thing you can try is to use a prepared statement with parameters to see how the execution plan looks if the value after `&&` is a parameter (run `EXPLAIN EXECUTE` six times for the generic plan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot think of any reason why such a query should behave differently inside a PL/pgSQL function; my experiments suggest that it doesn't.

- Run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on a query like you run inside the function several times to get a good estimate of the duration you are to expect.
- Run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on inserts like the ones you are doing in batch on a similar table *without* a trigger to measure how long heap insert and index maintenance will take.
- Add these values and multiply with the number of rows you insert in a batch.

If you end up with roughly the same time as you experience, there is no mystery to solve.

If you end up with a “lossy” bitmap index scan (look at `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output), you can boost the performance by increasing `work_mem`.